# Access a local file in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to get the string from a local file (probably a Csharp file), which is attached to current project and its build action was set to Compile. Is there any way to do that. I cannot set the files' build action into Resource.

Regards,
Jawahar

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear which of these two questions you're asking:

Question 1) Can I get the text of a source file used during compilation, after compilation?

Answer 1) You'd need to set the build action to Content or Resource to do that, but realize that means you'd be shipping your source with your xap, so make sure that's what you want to do (i.e. most employers probably wouldn't like this).

You can have the file added to the xap twice by using "Add -> Existing Item -> (pick the file) -> Add As Linked Item (the little drop-down arros next to Add buton)" and set one to Compile and one to Content/Resource to accomplish this.

Question 2) Can I access a local file on the hard drive of a user of the Silverlight application?

Answer 2) Yes, by using OpenFileDialog and having the user choose the file.

Or, if you're in a Trusted Out of Browser Application (SL4 and above), then you can use the System.IO APIs to access files in My Documents, My Pictures, My Videos or My Music (on Windows an Mac) without needing to prompt the user.

Or, if you're in a Trusted OOB app, running on Windows, you can use COM and access the full file system (up to what the user can see permission-wise), again without prompt.